# Matching series of Ampersands in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am unable to solve the below question.Requesting all to help me in this regard.

I have series of ampersands(&) in my data, I want to replace pair of ampersands with some value, but for some reason I am unable to do it.

**My attempt and example:**

```
string1 <- "This aa should be replaced: but this aaa shouldn't"
string2 <- "This && should be replaced: but this &&& shouldn't"

gsub("aa", "XXX", string1)       #1.
gsub("\\baa\\b", "XXX", string1) #2.

gsub("&&", "XXX", string2)       #3.
gsub("\\b&&\\b", "XXX", string2) #4.
```

Above, if I want to match 'aa' from string1, I can have two approaches,

In approach 1 (denoted as : #1), I can simply pass 'aa' but this will also match 'aaa' partially, which I don't want, I want my regex to match exactly pairs of 'a', which in my case is 'aa'.

To solve this I use regex (#2), In this case it is working fine.

Now, in string2, I expected a similar behavior, where instead of matching pair of 'a' I want to match pair of '&&' which is not matching.

The (#3) attempt is working, but that is not the result I want as it is also matching partially '&&&',

The (#4) attempt is not working for some reason and its not replacing the string.

**My question is:**

```
1) Why pair of ampersands are not working with boundary conditions ?

2) What is the way around to solve this problem ?
```

I really had the hard time, and wasted my entire day due to this and really feeling bad, tried finding the solution on google, not yet successful.

In case some one know, if its there please redirect me to a post. OR if someone finds its a duplicate please let me know, I will remove it.

Thanks for your help and reading the question.

**EDIT**: My word boundary is space for now.

**Outputs**:

```
> gsub("aa", "XXX", string1)
[1] "This XXX should be replaced: but this XXXa shouldn't"
> gsub("\\baa\\b", "XXX", string1)
[1] "This XXX should be replaced: but this aaa shouldn't"
> 
> gsub("&&", "XXX", string2)
[1] "This XXX should be replaced: but this XXX& shouldn't"
> gsub("\\b&&\\b", "XXX", string2)
[1] "This && should be replaced: but this &&& shouldn't"
>
```

**Note**: I have also checked with perl=TRUE, but its not working.

Comment: Please define your "word boundary". Is that whitespace and start/end of string? `\b` matches the locations between start/end of string and a word char, or between a word and a non-word char.

Comment: Then use `gsub("(?<!\\S)&&(?!\\S)", "XXX", string2, perl=TRUE)`. You misunderstood what `\b` does and what a "word" is in regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`\b` word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) means:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>     word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last
>     character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,
>     where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

The [`"\\b&&\\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/GU5ILk/2) pattern matches `&&` when it is enclosed with word chars, letters, digits or `_` chars.

To match *whitespace boundaries*, you may use

```
gsub("(?<!\\S)&&(?!\\S)", "XXX", string2, perl=TRUE)
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<!\\S)`  - a location not immediately preceded with a non-whitespace char (that is, there must be start of string or a whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location)
- `&&` -  a literal substring
- `(?!\\S)` -  a location not immediately followed with a non-whitespace char (that is, there must be end of string or a whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location).

Comment: Equivalently you could presumably use `"\\B&&\\B" to match _whitespace boundaries_ instead of lookarounds?

Comment: @MokeEire That is not an equivalent, `\B&&\B` match two ampersands when they are enclosed with non-word chars (chars other than letters, digits and underscores) or at the start/end of string.

Comment: Whitespace characters are included in non-word characters, correct?

Comment: @MokeEire Yes, whitespaces are non-word chars as they are not letters, digits or `_`. Whitespace boundaries are custom boundaries, less generic than (non)word boundaries.

Comment: Ah, so an ampersand would also count as a non-word boundary and thus produce the same "XXX&" in the original post?

Answer (score 0):

More specific, but you could use a 2-step function like so

```
replace2steps <- function(mystring, toreplace,replacement, toexclude, intermediate) {
  intermstring <- gsub(toexclude,  intermediate,string2)
  result <-  gsub(toreplace,  replacement, intermstring)
  result <-  gsub(intermediate,  toexclude, result)
  return(result)
}
replace2steps(string2, "&&", "XX", "&&&", "%%%")
[1] "This XX should be replaced: but this &&& shouldn't"
```